# Provided Maven Dependency which does not exist in repository but in container

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I have to use a library so I looked it up in our repository and added it to the dependencies. When starting the Weblogic server I got a DeploymentException (Ambiguous Bean Name).

I found out that this means that I try to register Beans with the same name twice or more.

Then I found out that this library is already provided by  the server (JEE Container). Therefore this exception makes sense. I then changed the scope of the dependency to `provided` and the version to the one provided by the container.

But then I got a build error because the dependency can't be resolved with that version. I checked our repo manually and saw that this is true.

- version provided by container: 1.0.4
- version existing in repo: 1.0.7

How can I resolve this issue? I just want to tell maven that it should use the library which will exist when deployed. And ignore the fact that it's not available during compilation. (If this is even possible)

Comment: have you tried using shaded plugin for building uber jar?

Comment: @PruthviChitrala I don't think I understand what you mean. Could you clarify please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood some aspects of "provided".

Giving a dependency as "provided" means that it is only used for compilation but not packaged into your war/ear. This implies that it does not make sense to specify a dependency as "provided" if it does not exist in the repository.

The usual way to solve your problem would be to specify the dependency with version 1.0.7 and make sure that you do not call any class/method that is not present in version 1.0.4.

Your application will then compile against 1.0.7 but runs with 1.0.4 which is fine in most cases (note that Java cannot check or know the versions of the included jars - the only risk is that 1.0.7 has different interfaces than 1.0.4 which is unlikely if only the last part of the number changed).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I was actually doing that - compiling against 1.0.7 and even tough I was calling classes and methods which didn't change since 1.0.4 it didn't work somehow. But after all I had to update our server version which is now packaged with 1.0.7 so the issue was resolved that way.

Comment: @Fabian, is there any way to say "Use my dependency from POM if it doesn't exist on the server"?

Comment: @user1182625 Don't know, but why not just look up first what's on the server? I mean, if you intend to build your project for multiple servers: This won't work anyway.